# robovm bindings configuration about *.dylib

Tags: robovm

I have an Objective C static library that I am trying to import into robovm project. The problem that I am encountering, though, is that the library depends on libz.dylib  and I do not know how to include these frameworks in my robovm application.

i can't find any configuration about *.dylib as follow
https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings
https://github.com/robovm/robovm/wiki/The-Bro-Java-to-native-bridge

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

I believe `libz` is included by `robovm` by default.

You don't need to do anything. I just created some bindings that required it, they work, and I didn't have to do anything.